# Identical to a continuous function a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Are the following two statements equivalent to each other?
>
> 1. $f$ is continuous almost everywhere
> 2. $f$ is identical to a continuous function almost everywhere.

What is meant with statement 2?

Is it: There is a continuous function $g\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f=g$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Or is it: There is a non-empty subset $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and a continuous function $g\colon D\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f=g$ a.e. on $D$?

Comment: For $n=1$, $f(x)=\cases{0, &$x$ rational\cr 1, &$x$ irrational}$, satisfies 2) but not 1).

Answer (score 1):

I would take your first option.

Concerning the second one: just take $D$ to be a set of empty measure, then $f = g$ a.e. on $D$ is always satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

For any $n\geq 1$, consider the functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(\vec{x})=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\vec{x}=\vec{0},\\
0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases} \qquad\quad g(\vec{x})=0\text{ for all }\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

The function $g$ is continuous, and $f=g$ almost everywhere, but $f$ is not continuous itself.